# 2 fragments after screen rotation, saved value lost

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, savestate

I've got problem with fragment based on FragmentLayout example from sample API
as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example

All works fine except when I want to save/restore value in the Bundle of DetailsFragment
to handle a screen rotation.

To illustrate this, I've modified the DetailsFragment of the FragmentLayout example
to append a random value
(to simulate an action on the fragment) at the bottom of the TextView
and this value is saved in onSaveInstanceState and retrieved in onCreateView.

### Now the problem:

1. start in portrait mode and select an item in list.
   The DetailsFragment is displayed as
   new Intent with a random value at the bottom.
2. rotate the device in landscape mode.
   The list is on the left side with the selected item
   highlighted (I moved the call of getListView().setItemChecked(mCurCheckPosition, true)
   in onStart method of TitlesFragment because it doesn't work
   when made in showDetail method) and on the right side,
   the DetailsFragment is displayed
   with text corresponding to the selected item but **the value
   is not the one who was saved
   but a new one**.
   As shown in log (see below), after the rotation a DetailsFragment is created and the random value is
   correctly restored but another instance is created by the TitleFragment because the
   findFragmentById returns null, and the DetailsFragment creates a new random value.
   **So there is
   two fragments, one visible with a wrong random value and another one somewhere, not visible,
   with the value I need!**

   **How to fix this to display the correct fragment and of course don't create a new one?**

   And if we continue rotating the device:
3. rotate back in portrait mode and select again the same item as in point 1
4. rotate again in landscape mode.
   Now the findFragmentById returns a fragment and as
   getShownIndex get the same value as the index, there is no new instance of DetailsFragment and **it displays the randon value shown at point 2**.

### Here is the log with comment

```
********************************************************
* 1. Start in portrait mode - select item 6 (Othello)  *
* new DetailsFragment created with new rand value 4769 *
* this value is saved in onSaveInstanceState           *
********************************************************

D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView
D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onActivityCreated
D/TitlesFragment(21894): onActivityCreated - portrait mode
D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onStart
D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering showDetails - index: 6
D/TitlesFragment(21894): showDetails - Single Pane - start new activity
D/TitlesFragment(21894): showDetails - position: 6 - title: Othello

D/DetailsActivity(21894): Entering onCreate
D/DetailsActivity(21894): onCreate - portrait mode
D/DetailsActivity(21894): onCreate - new DetailsFragment: DetailsFragment{41980540}

D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView - this: DetailsFragment{41980540 #0 id=0x1020002}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onCreateView - new mRandValue: 4769

D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onSaveInstanceState - save position: 6

D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onSaveInstanceState - this: DetailsFragment{41980540 #0 id=0x1020002}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onSaveInstanceState - save value: 4769


*********************************************************
* 2. Rotate in landscape mode                           *
* DetailsFragment created with rand value 4769 restored *
* Another DetailsFragment created for entry 6 (Othello) *
* with new rand value 5572                              *
*********************************************************

D/DetailsActivity(21894): Entering onCreate
D/DetailsActivity(21894): onCreate - landscape mode - finish

D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView - this: DetailsFragment{4199d458 #0 id=0x1020002}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onCreateView - restored randValue: 4769

D/FragmentLayout (Activity)(21894): Entering onCreate

D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView
D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onActivityCreated
D/TitlesFragment(21894): onActivityCreated - landscape mode
D/TitlesFragment(21894): onActivityCreated - dual pane, calling show details - position: 6
D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering showDetails - index: 6
D/TitlesFragment(21894): showDetails - DetailsFragment found by id: null
D/TitlesFragment(21894): showDetails - calling DetailsFragment newInstance for index: 6

D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering newInstance - index: 6
D/DetailsFragment(21894): newInstance: DetailsFragment{419e16a8}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView - this: DetailsFragment{419e16a8 #1 id=0x7f060004}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onCreateView - new mRandValue: 5572

D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onStart
D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onSaveInstanceState - save position: 6

D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onSaveInstanceState - this: DetailsFragment{419e16a8 #1 id=0x7f060004}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onSaveInstanceState - save value: 5572


*********************************************************
* 3. Rotate back in portrait mode                       *
* DetailsFragment created with rand value 5572 restored *
* Select again item 6 (Othello)                         *
* New DetailsFragment created with new rand value 5685  *
* Both DetailsFragment save each its rand value         *
*********************************************************

D/FragmentLayout (Activity)(21894): Entering onCreate

D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView
D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onActivityCreated
D/TitlesFragment(21894): onActivityCreated - portrait mode

D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView - this: DetailsFragment{419e6248 #1 id=0x7f060004}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onCreateView - restored randValue: 5572

D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onStart
D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering showDetails - index: 6
D/TitlesFragment(21894): showDetails - Single Pane - start new activity
D/TitlesFragment(21894): showDetails - position: 6 - title: Othello

D/DetailsActivity(21894): Entering onCreate
D/DetailsActivity(21894): onCreate - portrait mode
D/DetailsActivity(21894): onCreate - new DetailsFragment: DetailsFragment{419bcf98}

D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView - this: DetailsFragment{419bcf98 #0 id=0x1020002}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onCreateView - new mRandValue: 5685

D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onSaveInstanceState - save position: 6

D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onSaveInstanceState - this: DetailsFragment{419e6248 #1 id=0x7f060004}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onSaveInstanceState - save value: 5572
D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onSaveInstanceState - this: DetailsFragment{419bcf98 #0 id=0x1020002}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onSaveInstanceState - save value: 5685


******************************************************************
* 4. Rotate again in landscape mode                              *
* DetailsFragment created with rand value 5685 restored          *
* DetailsFragment found by id with same index 6, no new instance *
* the found fragment is created with rand value 5572 restored,   *
* this is the rand value visible in point 2.                     *
******************************************************************

D/DetailsActivity(21894): Entering onCreate
D/DetailsActivity(21894): onCreate - landscape mode - finish

D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView - this: DetailsFragment{419c2fc0 #0 id=0x1020002}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onCreateView - restored randValue: 5685

D/FragmentLayout (Activity)(21894): Entering onCreate

D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView
D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onActivityCreated
D/TitlesFragment(21894): onActivityCreated - landscape mode
D/TitlesFragment(21894): onActivityCreated - dual pane, calling show details - position: 6
D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering showDetails - index: 6
D/TitlesFragment(21894): showDetails - DetailsFragment found by id: DetailsFragment{41a07e08 #1 id=0x7f060004}
D/TitlesFragment(21894): showDetails - details.getShownIndex: 6

D/DetailsFragment(21894): Entering onCreateView - this: DetailsFragment{41a07e08 #1 id=0x7f060004}
D/DetailsFragment(21894): onCreateView - restored randValue: 5572

D/TitlesFragment(21894): Entering onStart
```

### And part of code where I put some modifications

in TitlesFragment:

```
public class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment
{
    private final String TAG = "TitlesFragment";

    ...
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Entering onStart");
        super.onStart();
        if (mDualPane) {
            // call here because doesn't work when called in showDetails
            getListView().setItemChecked(mCurCheckPosition, true);
        }
    }

    ...
    void showDetails(int index) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Entering showDetails - index: " + index);
        mCurCheckPosition = index;

        if (mDualPane) {
            // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
            // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
            // This doesn't work here, moved in onStart
            //getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

            // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
            DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
            Log.d(TAG, "showDetails - DetailsFragment found by id: " + details);
            if (details != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "showDetails - details.getShownIndex: " + details.getShownIndex());
            }

            if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
                Log.d(TAG, "showDetails - calling DetailsFragment newInstance for index: " + index);

                // Make new fragment to show this selection.
                details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

                // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
                // with this one inside the frame.
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                //if (index == 0) {
                    ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
                //} else {
                    // following crash!!
                    //ft.replace(R.id.a_item, details);
                //}
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "showDetails - Single Pane - start new activity");
            Log.d(TAG, "showDetails - position: " + index + " - title: " + getListAdapter().getItem(index));

            // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
            // the dialog fragment with selected text.
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", index);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }    
}
```

and in DetailsFragment:

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment
{
    private final String TAG = "DetailsFragment";

    private int mRandValue = 9999;

    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Entering onCreateView - this: " + this.toString());

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mRandValue = savedInstanceState.getInt("randValue", 8888);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView - restored randValue: " + mRandValue);
        }

        if (container == null) {
            // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
            // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
            // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
            // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
            // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could
            // just run the code below, where we would create and return
            // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
            return null;
        }

        ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(getActivity());
        TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        int padding = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                4, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        text.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        scroller.addView(text);
        final int idx = getShownIndex();
        text.setText(Shakespeare.TITLES[idx] + "\n\n" + Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[idx]);
        //text.setText(Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[getShownIndex()]);

        // create a new random value to simultate an action in the fragment
        if (mRandValue > 7000) {
            mRandValue = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() % 7000);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView - new mRandValue: " + mRandValue);
        }
        text.append("\n\nRand Value = " + mRandValue);

        return scroller;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle _outState)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Entering onSaveInstanceState - this: " + this.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState - save value: " + mRandValue);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(_outState);
        _outState.putInt("randValue", mRandValue);
    }
}
```

### Again my question

**What I have to change to correctly handle the rotation?**
The 'rand value' is something made on the DetailsFragment I want to keep!

Answer (score 0):

Rotation recreates your activity You will have to override onsaved instances and save the values that you need in it.......
then in onResume() method you can fetch those values

Comment: I've overrided onSaveInstanceState to save the value in my fragment and I retrieve the value in onCreateView, this is what I've explained.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its better to call super.onSaveInstanceState after your putInt:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle _outState)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Entering onSaveInstanceState - this: " + this.toString());
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState - save value: " + mRandValue);

    **_outState.putInt("randValue", mRandValue);**
    super.onSaveInstanceState(_outState);

}
```